# Salesforce: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field

Tags: c#, wpf, salesforce, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer

I'm working on an application that creates and save invoices on salesforce cloud but when i try to create a transaction i get the following error

"SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document_Type__c.s2cor__Use_Company_Shipping__c"

below is my code for creating the transaction

```
SuccessResponse createTransResponse = await client.CreateAsync("s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document__c", transaction);
```

the Transaction class is created like so

```
public class Transaction
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public string s2cor__Reference__c { get; set; }
        public String s2cor__Account__c { get; set; }
        public String s2cor__Date__c { get; set; }
        public string s2cor__Trade_Document_Type__c = "a211v0000022YBpAAM"; // use this
        //public string s2cor__Net_Amount__c { get; set; }
        public string s2cor__Currency__c { get; set; }
        public string s2cor__Exchange_Rate__c { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for triggers defined on the "s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document__c" SObject in Salesforce. Looks like an error in a trigger to me.

Comment: Thanks @Suraj. so how do i resolve the issue if the trigger is causing it?

Comment: Check if there is a SOQL query in the trigger that is querying the records for "s2cor__Trade_Document_Type__c " using the record id you have in your code (a211v0000022YBpAAM). If the query does not include the "s2cor__Use_Company_Shipping__c" field, add it to the list of fields in the query.

Comment: I would advise that you work with a Salesforce developer to get this sorted.